# when i run npm install react-currency format . I'm getting the below error? what can i do?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

```
PS C:\Users\ELCOT\amazon-clone-app> npm install react-currency-format    
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: amazon-clone-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!   react-currency-format@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-24T17_38_45_526Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\ELCOT\amazon-clone-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

run this cmd npm install react-currency-format --save --force

Answer (score 1):

Currently, React has come up with an update. So, this package has to be installed forcefully by using --force and --save together.

```
 npm install react-currency-format --save --force
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed react yet. you have to install react first before installing react-currency-format.
as you can see below, react is not installed.

> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 ||
> ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0" from
> react-currency-format@1.0.0

you can see  that it requires react to be installed first.
do a

```
npm i react
```

And then do

```
npm i react-currency-format
```

Comment: npm ERR! While resolving: amazon-clone-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2 ,///He already had react I think react-currency-format is not updated after react@16.0.0 hence it is showing dependency could not resolve, --force will be better option here